# Rijndael: explanation of Rcon on Wikipedia?

Tags: rijndael

I stumbled onto the explanation of [Rijndael Rcon on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_key_schedule), and I can't follow it.

The example for Rcon indicates that *Rcon(9)* is `0x1b`.
That could make sense… `rcon(9) = (2 ^ (9 - 1) mod (256)) + 16 + 8 + 2 + 1`

But I don't understand *Rcon(10)* or anything past that.

Can someone please explain it to me? Also, why is *Rcon(0)* = `0x8d`?

Answer (score 5):

Rcon(9) is `0x1b` because `0x80` multiplied by `0x02` is `0x100`, which is reduced to `0x00 xor 0x1b` in the finite field.

Rcon(10) is twice Rcon(9), and so forth.

Rcon(0) is `0x8d` because `0x8d` multiplied by `0x02` is `0x01` in the finite field.

If what I mean by *finite field* is not understood, it is because the numbers you are dealing with are actually polynomials, see: [Rijndael's Finite Field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_Galois_field#Rijndael.27s_finite_field)

Comment: Thanks, that is what I saw on some other pages. What I can't follow is Wikipedia's explanation. Can you take a look at that and explain what they mean. For example, what does:
rcon(i) = x^(i-1) mod x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1
mean, and how does that work for rcon(10)?

Comment: x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1 is the reduction polynomial 0x11B, that sentence from Wikipedia is technically incorrect, as modulo 0x11B only happens if the value exceeds 0xFF